# How to disable manual input through iPad keyboard for Bootstrap Datepicker field in iPad

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ipad, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

I am using bootstrap-datepicker.js for displaying a field using datepicker. In iPad, iPad keyboard is popping up along with datepicker, which should not happen in my scenario.

> I used making "readonly" in the html template for that field, and used ignoreReadOnly, which is not supporting with bootstrap-datepicker. May be it is for datetimepicker. By this datepicker itself not coming up in iPad.

I also used:

```
$('.applyDatepicker').datepicker({
    format: "mm-dd-yyyy",
    autoclose: true,
    todayHighlight: true
}).on('focus', function(e){
    $(this).trigger('blur');
});
```

This code is just popping up and hiding the iPad keyboard on focus, for selecting value using datepicker. The problem is when i want to change the year value, i click on datepicker year value, and again iPad keyboard popsup for editing.

I just want to use only datepicker to select date and not the iPad keyboard.
How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: I got the answer guys. I am mentioning it below fyi.

Comment: I used an calendar icon beside the field. On click to icon, we have to apply datepicker to the textfield. Code is below.

Comment: **HTML template** '<div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <input type="text" name="birthdate"                                         id="bday" placeholder="MM-DD-YYYY" readonly>
                                         <label>Birthday</label>
                               </div>
                               <div class="datepker"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></div>'

Comment: **View** 'onShow: function(e){
                    $("#bday").datepicker({
                        format: "mm-dd-yyyy",
                        autoclose: true
                    });
                    $(".datepker").on("click", function() {
                        $("#bday").datepicker("show");
                    });}'